# Как защититься от подмены значения параметра в URL?

Tags: php

Банальный пример, имеется страница с формой заявки по адресу order.php?id=2
где 2 - есть номер заявки.
Как защититься от подмены параметра id другим числом? Т-е если человек впишет 3 - то заказ отправится в слот для оптовиков.

Comment: а надо не давать ему такие данные сообщать, проверяйте, если оптовик, то можно а не оптовик - еггог ему

Comment: То есть, id определяет не номер заявки, а тип?

Comment: Неужели так сложно отделить данные, которые нужно получить от пользователя, от данных, мнение юзера о которых нас не mc^2бёт? Если вы спрашиваете у пользователя, оптовик ли он - то пусть подменяет, нет проблемы. А если эти данные выставляет администратор для конкретного пользователя - то нафига передавать их через массив `$_REQUEST`? Храните в БД, выгружайте в сессию. Если же "оптовитость" зависит от суммы заказа... Впрочем, итак уже много букв написал. Исправляйте логику.

Comment: Что-то Ваш характер совсем не соответствует нику, Равнодушный =)
Пы.Сы.: Сори за оффтоп.

Comment: Спасибо - будем ждать еще мнения. а так смысл ясен

Comment: @IOleg 2 и 3 это номер заказа или тип заказа? а то по тексту путается.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать дополнительный параметр запроса, который равен хэшу всех остальных. При обработке запроса заново рассчитывать хэш и сравнивать с полученным. Если значения совпадают значит все ок!

**Преимущества:** простота реализации.

**Недостатки:** возможность подмены хэша; необходимость пересылать дополнительный набор данных в запросах.

Но, по-хорошему, Вам нужно постоянно синхронизировать данные с сервером при помощи AJAX. Тут и параметров запросов не нужно. Про100 привязка по SESSIONID или любом другом уникальном ID.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте маршрутизацию.

Например, введите параметр **recipient**, значением которого будет имя модуля, в который отсылаете данные, а уже в самом модуле проверяйте, правильный ли набор данных вам пришел.

Если вам необходимо одним пользователям позволять только одни действия, а другим пользователям - другие - используйте ACL (Списки контроля доступа).

Comment: Не полностью вас понял. в параметре мне нужно передать не только имя модуля но и номер заявки

Comment: Ну так и передавайте, в чем проблема? indes.php?recipient=sales&param1=value1&param2=value2

Comment: и в чем проблема подменить value2 ???

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать валидаторы?